# Django tastypie: Add new Array of objects Next to "objects" and "meta" in Api output

Tags: django, python-2.7, tastypie

In Django tastypie, i have this output from an Api.

```
{ 
 "meta": {
    "limit": 1000,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 2
  },
 "objects": [
    {},
    {}
   ]
}
```

i want to extend the output data. what i need is add new Array of objects named "Images" next to "objects" that is separate from "objects" data, like this:

```
{ 
 "meta": {
    "limit": 1000,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 2
  },
 "objects": [
    {},
    {}
   ],
 "images": [
    {},
    {}
   ]
}
```

How can i Implement it with tastypie of Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For list responses you can use **[Resource.alter_list_data_to_serialize](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#alter-list-data-to-serialize)**

```python
class PageDataAddition(object):
    def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
        data['page'] = {'your_data': True}
        return data

class ItemResource(PageDataAddition, ModelResource):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Inherit your class from **Resource** and define both of them as **ListField** like below :

```
objects = fields.DictField(attribute='objects')

categories = fields.ListField(attribute='category')
```